# EXCEL - SUM column grouped by part of string of other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this table:

[image]

How to sum all amount in column B for the first two chars in column A?

For example: SUM all amounts for LUxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into the SUMIF function in conjunction with LEFT() which will enable you to get the first two characters.

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry, it was stupid question. Just divide column A to two colums (`LEFT (A;2)` and `RIGHT(A;2)`) and make contingency table:-) hurry slowly....

Comment: There is a more easier way to do this, check my answer

Answer (score 7):

SUMIF can do this. You can try the below function (I already tested):

```
=SUMIF(A2:A20,"LU*",B2:B20)
```

- *A2:A20* is the range you want to look into
- *"LU*"* means you only want the records which start with LU in A2:A20
- *B2:B20* is the actual range that you use to sum

Don't forget to change the number in the range according to your Excel content!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make diagonalbatman's solution work (I don't think that `SUMIF` do accept formula).

Here is a `SUMPRODUCT` formula solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B24*IF(LEFT(A1:A24;2)="LU",1,0))
```

May have to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (should work without but sometimes, it isn't well interpreted by `SUMPRODUCT`).

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry, it was stupid answer. Just divide column A to two colums (`LEFT (A;2)` and `RIGHT(A;2)`) and make contingency table:-) hurry slowly....

Answer (score 2):

To use the SUMIF approach, add an intermediate column (say column C) with formula:

```
=LEFT(A2,2)
```

and copy down for each row used.  Then use:

```
=SUMIF(C2:C19,"LU",B2:B19)
```